# The program will not let me get the last three scores of each student

Tags: python, list, file, text

```
print("Hello, and welcome to the Maths quiz!")

#Asks user for name
name = input("What is your name? ")

class_number = input("What is your class number? Class 1, 2 or 3? Please enter an integer, no letters.")

#This will import random to generate random functions
import random

#This is a variable for score
#It has been set to 0 at the start of the program
score = 0

scores={}
scores[name]=[]

#This creates an array containing the mathematical operators
#that this quiz will use
ops = ['+','-','*']

#A loop has been set for 0 - 10
for x in range(10):
    #This is variable has been set to the operator of the equation that
    #uses the random function and will choose a random operator from the
    #array containing the operators made earlier
    op = random.choice(ops)
    #The if statement checks if the operation is an addition operation
    if op == '+':
        #This will generate a random number between 1 and 100
        #for the first integer
        first1 = random.randint(1,100)
        #This will generate a random number between 1
        #and 100 for the first integer
        second1 = random.randint(1,100)
        #This print function will generate a mathematical question
        print ("What is " + (str(first1) + op + str(second1) + "?"))
        #This eval function will generate the answer to the mathematical
        #question asked and store it in the answer variable
        answer  = eval(str(first1) + op + str(second1))
        #This will loop the try statement until an integer is entered as the guess variable
        while True:
            #The try statement will see if the guess variable is given an integer value,
            #if not then it will print "You did not enter an integer. This is not a
            #valid answer
            try:
                #This will allow the user to enter their answer and
                #store it in the guess variable
                guess = int(input(""))
                #This will break the while loop if an integer is entered as the guess variable
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("You did not enter an integer. This is not a valid answer. Please enter a valid integer")
                print("Answer the quesiton appropiately. " + "What is " + (str(first1) + op + str(second1)) + "?")
        if guess == answer:
            #If the guess1 variable is equal to the answer1 variable, then
            #"Correct!" will be printed and one point would be
            #added to the score
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            #If the guess variable is equal to the answer variable, then
            #"Correct!" will be printed and one point would be
            #added to the score
            #Else "Incorrect" would be printed
            print("Incorrect")
    #The elif statement checks if the operation is a subtraction operation
    elif op == '-':
        #This will generate a random number between 1 and 20 (because over 20 could be too hard for the students)
        #for the first integer and stores it as the left2 variable
        first2 = random.randint(1,20)
        #This will generate a random number between 1
        #and 20 (because over 20 could be too hard for the students) for the second integer and stores it as the right2 variable
        second2 = random.randint(1,20)
        #This print function will generate a mathematical question
        print ("What is " + (str(first2) + op + str(second2) + "?"))
        #This eval function will generate the answer to the mathematical
        #question asked and store it in the answer1 variable
        answer1 = eval(str(first2) + op + str(second2))
        #This will loop the try statement until an integer is entered as the guess1 variable
        while True:
            #The try statement will see if the guess variable is given an integer value,
            #if not then it will print "You did not enter an integer. This is not a
            #valid answer
            try:
                #This will allow the user to enter their answer and
                #store it in the guess1 variable
                guess1 = int(input(""))
                #This will break the while loop if an integer is entered as the guess1 variable
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("You did not enter an integer. This is not a valid answer. Please enter a valid integer")
                print("Answer the question appropiately. " + "What is " + (str(first2) + op + str(second2)) + "?")
        if guess1 == answer1:
            #If the guess1 variable is equal to the answer1 variable, then
            #"Correct!" will be printed and one point would be
            #added to the score
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            #Else "Incorrect" would be printed
            print ("Incorrect")
    #The second elif statement checks if the operation is a multiplication
    #operation
    elif op == '*':
        #This generates the first number as a random number between
        #1 and 12 (because the students would be tested on their multiplication table)
        #used in the multiplication calculation
        #and stores it as the left3 variable
        first3 = random.randint(1,12)
        #This generates the second number as a random number between
        #1 and 12 (because the students would be tested on their multiplication table)
        #used in the multiplication calculation
        #and stores it as the left3 variable
        second3 = random.randint(1,12)
        #This generates the multiplcation question
        print ("What is " + (str(first3) + op + str(second3) + "?"))
        #This creates the answer for the multiplication question and
        #stores it as the answer2 variable
        answer2 = eval(str(first3) + op + str(second3))
        #This will loop the try statement until an integer is entered as the guess2 variable
        while True:
            #The try statement will see if the guess variable is given an integer value,
            #if not then it will print "You did not enter an integer. This is not a
            #valid answer
            try:
                #This allows the user to enter their own answer and store it as
                #the guess2 variable
                guess2 = int(input(""))
                #This will break the while loop if an integer is entered as the guess2 variable
                break
            except ValueError:
                print("You did not enter an integer. This is not a valid answer. Please enter a valid integer.")
                print("Answer the quesiton appropiately. " + "What is " + (str(first3) + op + str(second3)) + "?")
        #The if statement checks if the answer the user entered is equal
        #to the answer of the question
        if guess2 == answer2:
            #If the guess2 variable is equal to the answer2 variable, then
            #"Correct!" will be printed and one point would be
            #added to the score
            print("Correct!")
            score += 1
        else:
            #Else "Incorrect" would be printed
            print ("Incorrect")
    else:
        #Else if the operation is not an addition, subtration or multiplcation
        #operation then the break statement would be enacted and the
        #the whole if statement would stop. However, this
        #will be unlikely to happen since an operation would be chosen
        #by the program
        break 
#This will print out the user's score out of 10
print ("You got " + str(score) + "/10, " + name + " " + "from class " + class_number)

#This will create a new variable that connects both the class_number variable and
#the "Class" string so it would come out as "Class class_number".
class_tag = "Class "+ class_number

#This will create and open a new text file under the name
#of the class_tag variable.
file = open(class_tag + ".txt", "a")
#This will write down the user's name and their score
file.write(str(name) + " scored " + str(score))
#This will create a new line for each user
file.write("\n")
#This will close the file.
file.close()

user_scores = {}
user_scores[name].append(score)
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
        user_scores[name] = score
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    print(name, '-', user_scores[name])
print(user_scores[name][-3:])
```

I have created a program that allows students to do a quiz and their scores are stored in a text file that is based on their class. I'm trying to use the text files to get data from it and order their scores in the terms of the their last three, so the user can use it. However, when I tried:

```
user_scores = {}
#This adds to the list of names
user_scores[name].append(score)
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
        user_scores[name] = score
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    print(name, '-', user_scores[name])
print(user_scores[name][-3:])
```

The IDLE shell came back with:
    user_scores[name].append(score)
KeyError: 'student'

The Class 0 text file's data is:

```
student scored 3
student scored 8
student scored 0
student scored 4
student scored 10
student scored 3
student scored 0
student scored 4
```

Class 3 text file's data is:

```
katy scored 0
katy scored 2
katy scored 0
katy scored 6
```

`user_scores` will be a list full of lists, so one list of scores per name.

UPDATE:
I tried:

```
user_scores = []
user_scores[name].append(score)
for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' - ')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores or user_scores[name] < score:
        user_scores[name] = score
for name in sorted(user_scores):
    print(name, '-', user_scores[name])
print(user_scores[name][-3:])
```

But the IDLE shell stated:

```
    user_scores[name].append(score)
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

So how would I get the program to get the last three score's of the student based on their name? I tried using many other methods and none of them have worked.

Comment: Don't repeat yourself: what is the difference between the three if-op-Blocks? Write a function, put the differences in parameters, use this one function.

Comment: Use `.format` for string-formatting, not `str` and `+`.

Comment: Don't use `eval`. The code is hard to maintain, and errors cannot be detected.

Answer (score 0):

Here:

```
user_scores = {}
user_scores[name].append(score)
```

You are trying to append an item to a list, but `user_scores[name]` is not a list, because user_scores is an empty dictionary.

If you want something quick and dirty that will do what you want, then:

```
user_scores = {}

for line in scores:
    name, score = line.rstrip('\n').split(' scored ')
    score = int(score)
    if name not in user_scores:
        user_scores[name] = []
    user_scores[name].append(score)

for name in sorted(user_scores.keys()):
    print(name + '-' + user_scores[name])

print(user_scores[name][-3:])
```

There are multiple problems with your code, but something like this at least would give you the output that you want. I kept the print syntax you used earlier in the code for consistency, but as mentioned you should use other techniques.

Comment: So, what should I do with it? How can I make user_scores a list, rather than a dictionary? Should I try: 'user_scores = []'?

Comment: I'm sorry, could you clarify exactly what it is that you want your code to do? What I gather so far is: 1. Ask for user name.  2. Ask for user class. 3. Gives the user a quiz with 10 questions, and keeps track of the user score. 4. Adds user score to text file for user's class. 5. ??? What do you exactly want to output to the user after the user takes the test?

Comment: Then output the user's last three scores. However, the user can find the scores of any user and their scores that is stored in the text file based on the class of the user called for.

Comment: I modified my answer. I'm assuming you want something that just works. There are multiple issues with your code as mentioned before by others, but this might work.

Comment: A `collections.defaultdict` could make this code a bit simpler.